# AngularJs user registration form: add a "repeat password" & check that passwords match

Tags: angularjs

I would like to use the AngularJs user registration from http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx However, it only prompts for the password once.

I would like to add a "repeat password field **and** also verify that both passwords are the same.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <div ng-show="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.error}}</div>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.register()" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error.required }">
            <label for="name">Full name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.name" required />
            <span ng-show="form.name.$dirty && form.name.$error.required" class="help-block">First name is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.required }">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.email" required />
            <span ng-show="form.email.$dirty && form.email.$error.required" class="help-block">Last name is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Requested username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.username" required />
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.password" required />
            <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
```

### - I am adding this, but it doesn't work :-(

```
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password2.$dirty && form.password2.$error.required }">
            <label for="password2">Repeat password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.password2" required />
            <span ng-show="form.password2.$dirty && form.password2.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
            <span ng-show="form.password2.$dirty && form.password2.$error.required && form.password2 != form.password" class="help-block">Passwords do not match</span>
```

### -

```
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
            <a href="#/login" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: [Are you able to use this](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/matching-two-fields) so that you do not have to re-invent ? Sometimes it is not possible to use ext libraries but since you already import NG, thought I'd share.

Comment: I would prefer to edit the existing code, but this does look like a possibility. Feel free to add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check in your `ng-show` doesn't work because you're trying to compare angular objects not the values of inputs. `form.password2 != form.password` should be `form.password2.$modelValue != form.password.$modelValue`.

And second you don't need the `form.password2.$error.required` check for matching validation. It ruins logic

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6SzFwEGOx0xE4Sm9n9UY?p=preview). Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This logic belongs in your controller (or factory, etc), not in the view.  You can do something like:

```
vm.register = function() {
    if (vm.user.password !== vm.user.password2) { 
        vm.alert = 'Passwords must match';
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Accidentally chopped before submitting. I've added it back.

Comment: Well, I _could_ do that, and will if I don't hear how to do it in the existing code. However, I could only do that check after the "Register" button was pushed - and the point of the JS in the view seems to be to use JS to offer error hints on the form *not with a pop-up alert) and not to enable the "Register" button until the input is valid.

Comment: Just to be clear 'alert' is not a pop-up alert.  It's a variable you'd set in the controller and pick up in the view where you show the error hint.  You can use the word 'error' or 'error_message' instead of 'alert' if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use directive:

```
.directive('passwordError', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope : {
        message : "="
      },
      link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.on('keydown', function(){
          scope.message = '';
          return ngModel.$setValidity('passwordError', true);
        })
      }
    }
  })

  .directive('pwCheck', function(){
    return {
      require : 'ngModel',
      scope : {
        newPassword: '=match'
      },
      link:function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
        scope.$watch('newPassword', function(){
          ngModel.$setValidity('matchError', element.val() === scope.newPassword);
        })
        element.on('keyup', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            ngModel.$setValidity('matchError', element.val() === scope.newPassword);
          })
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rPRQEqeOqDC9zKbietct?p=preview)